# where to check which dcm/pll supported in which xilinx fpga technology?

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-ise

Please tell me where to look for supported DCM/PLL on xilinx fpga technology .
Example - DCM_ADV supported in virtex 4 but not in xcv5

Answer (score 1):

Xilinx offers a "Library Guide for HDL Designs" for each ISE Version and each FPGA Family. This User Guide (UG) lists all available soft and hard macros for the given FPGA family.

For example:

- UG621 for Virtex-5
- UG623 for Virtex-6
- UG768 for 7-Series